Almost all emoji can render except two that are decoupled?
My question is very similar to this one : Flutter is decoupling emojis?
By using the noto notoColorEmoji as mentioned in the previous post, (notoColorEmojiCompat is not available anymore in the font package) i can get most emojis to render except for these two :
https://emojipedia.org/head-shaking-horizontally  ‍↔️
https://emojipedia.org/head-shaking-vertically  ‍↕️
(which both are labeled as "NEW" at this time or writing).
Both of these when copied from the emojipedia site also do not render correctly here!
I can see them in native emoji keyboard in the android emulator but if i input them they display as
‍↔️ for horizontally
‍↕️ for vertically
I would like not only for the emojis to display properly but also prevent this behavior altogether for future emojis that aren't working correctly. This decoupling breaks my UI because the user is asked to select a single emoji, but by doing so with these two, two appear instead. -__-
In short, i would like my app to support all possible types of emoji and never fail to render as a single emoji any emoji that appear on any emoji keyboard.
@gopelkujo i am editing the first post to show you the following image. It seems like i have the same problem on my host Linux computer (Fedora 40), i noticed in Firefox in the LinkedIn chat i get the same behavior and i have two emojis taking the place of one, both for the new emojis. (One duo is larger than the other because i was hovering with my mouse, to show that hovering over that spot pops up both emojis, as they are placeholders for what should be a single emoji)
My guess is some package is outdated compared to the current emoji spec and LinkedIn is ahead of Fedora or Firefox on something, but i am unsure what it could be.


I tested using plain Text Text('‍↔️ ‍↕️', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)) it looks fine

@gopelkujo just to be sure, when you run this code do you see 2 emojis or 4 emojis? When i run the code i see 4 :/ I am unsure why. These emojis seem to be new, yet i am running on the latest android emulator?

ah yess, in android it show 4 emojis, but in iOS it's running normal, sorry for my mistakes

@gopelkujo I edited the answer to show you something i found, is that the emojis are also showing as a duo in LinkedIn chat, in Firefox on my machine. It seems like it's an outdated package or something. Maybe your iOS emulator is newer than your android emulator? Can you tell me the versions you are using for that behavior?


In short, i would like my app to support all possible types of emoji and never fail to render as a single emoji any emoji that appear on any emoji keyboard.

This is not possible. What you're seeing is the correct behavior for an unsupported ZWJ (zero-width joiner) sequence, including emoji like these. These were added in Unicode 15.1. The rendering engine you use must at least support Unicode 15.1 to display them. Even if you built your own rendering engine from scratch, you would not be able to support future ZWJ Sequences you don't know about. This is true of any character in Unicode. The rendering engine has to know how to handle it, or it won't display it correctly.
Even if the rendering engine supports an emoji, the font may not. It has to have a glyph. If it doesn't, there's no way to show it.
Some websites do not use fonts to display emoji. They insert their own images. You can often see this when the emoji shows up after the text (sometimes even a few seconds after the text).
To the specific case of unsupported ZWJ Sequences, I do not recommend trying to fix this, but if you did it would look like this:
You could parse the text, search for ZWJ Sequences (they include the character U+200D), keep a list of all the ZWJ Sequences your font supports, and if it is not supported, then replace the sequence with the character you would like to show.
As an example, you would evaluate "‍↔️", which is the sequence ", U+200D, ↔️".  You would look this up in the table you would need to create of sequences your font supports. If it is not on it, you would delete the U+200D and ↔️, leaving . IMO, however, this would generally be bad for users, since it would change the meaning of the character. IMO, ↔️ is a better way to render this since it loses less information. But you can implement what you believe is best for your users.
Similar problems exist for emoji like Scientist ‍, which would be reduced to Person , or Transgender Flag ️‍⚧️, which would be reduced to White Flag ️. I think those kinds of changes would be very confusing, and a messed up emoji would be clearer (which is why it's the standard to show all of them).

Wow this is an incredibly good answer. Thank you for taking the time to post this. I am sure this well detailed answer will help future users understand the issue.

What i find very weird is that these emojis are displayed in the on-screen stock google keyboard in the Android 35 emulator (you can select them) but they do not render correctly in current latest flutter (3.24). I am forcing the font in the textbox to be Noto Color Emoji, so i would expect the emoji to show up correctly just like on the test site here : https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji

If you want to test on the previous comment you can copy the emoji from here : https://emojipedia.org/head-shaking-horizontally
